# Grouping of data using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a query related to summing of value based on group of data available in a csv file.

My file is test.csv file and data looks like below where the first line is a header, followed by 6 lines of data.

```
EntryId,datasource,Id,bookID,securId,Type,transfer,event,ActivityType,curr_code,sourceSystemDate,actualDate,accNumber,dr_cr_Type,dr_cr_Amount,remarks,asOfDate,custregion,custName,GLSuffix,product,Code,Domicile,departCode,TXT1,TXT2,TXT3
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,340,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,900,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,300,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,10,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582329,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,20,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582329,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,20,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
```

Some commands which I tried are

```
$ sed '1d' test.csv | awk -F ',' '$14=="Credit"{k = $1","$2","$3; x[k]+=$15; } END{for(k in x){print x[k]}}'
640
20
$ sed '1d' test.csv | awk -F ',' '$14=="Debit"{k = $1","$2","$3; x[k]+=$15; } END{for(k in x){print x[k]}}'
910
20
```

Now I have to calculate two balances:

1) the sum of credit balance in field 15, grouped by the first 3 fields

2) the sum of debit balance in field 15, grouped by the first 3 fields

If the balances are not matching, then it should display all the lines containing the grouping fields i.e. 1,2,3.

I want to do this in single awk statement with if conditions but I am not sure about how to try.

In the case that the debit balance is not equal to the credit balance, it should print all the lines corresponding to the grouping fields.

In the commands above, you see that the output is not matching so all the lines pertaining to that mismatch should be printed (in this case the first 4 lines)

The expected output in the case above should be:

```
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,340,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,900,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,300,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,10,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
```

if the balances are matched, then no action are to be taken.

Thanks and regards,

Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: I have tried to reformat your post, please check. `how to try about.` - just instead of using `x` and `k` variables use different ones. And then compare.

Comment: A couple of observations about your question vs your comments under the answers below - 1) you said `I want to do this in single awk statement` but seem OK with a solution that's awk + 2 seds + bashisms so maybe you'd be OK with a `sort | awk` solution to avoid a 2-pass awk one, 2) your input data has only decimals but `[Dr=Cr] won't match. In my earlier assignment had used printf "%.2f\n"` implies you are actually dealing with floating point numbers which makes sense if you're dealing with money but makes the arithmetic more interesting so you should include that in your example.

Comment: Also - your example could have had, say, 5 fields instead of 30 or whatever that is and so made it easier for us to see/understand the relevant values in your data - in future please post **minimal** examples that demonstrate your problem. Any time your example requires either a horizontal or vertical scroll bar it's too big.

Comment: Hi Ed, 
Point taken, next time would keep sample to minimal attributes as scroll is avoided.
Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR==1 { next }
{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 }
NR == FNR {
    bal[key] += ($14 == "Credit" ? 1 : -1) * $15
    next
}
bal[key]

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,340,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,900,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,300,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,10,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    sign["Credit"] = 1
    sign["Debit"] = -1
}
FNR==1 { next }
{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 }
NR == FNR {
    bal[key] += sign[$14] * $15
    next
}
bal[key]

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,340,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,900,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,300,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,10,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
```

Comment: Thanks Ed for your response, will check and revert back to you. 
I would accordingly change FNR to obtain the result. 
Regards, 
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: Good idea to add a line `{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 }` before the other statements. I suppose you allow me to include that into my code.

Comment: Why not `bal[key] += ($14 == "Credit" ? $15 : -$15)` instead of `bal[key] += ($14 == "Credit" ? 1 : -1) * $15`?

Comment: @PierreFrançois I expect that'd be fine too. The reason for doing it as I did is so that if the field number with the value changes from 15 to 23 or whatever there's just 1 place to change but the duplicated `$15` required doing it the way you asked about is not a big deal in this case.

Comment: @pbillaha since you really do want to skip the header line I made the tweak to my answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the file twice with one awk command as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awk -F ',' '
{ k = $1 "," $2 "," $3 }
FNR == NR && $14 == "Credit" {
  balance[k] += $15; 
} 
FNR == NR && $14 == "Debit" {
  balance[k] -= $15;
} 
FNR < NR {
  if (balance [k]) print
}' <(sed 1d test.csv) <(sed 1d test.csv)
```

Explanation: `<(sed 1d test.csv)` at the end of your awk command (see last line of the script), reads as input the output of `sed 1d test.csv`, which skips the head as you know. It does it twice. The first time to populate the array `balance[]`, and the second time to print the non matching lines when balance is not equal to `0`.

The condition `FNR == NR` is true only for the first pass. Otherwise, `FNR < NR` is true. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106645/processing-two-files-using-awk for more explanation about this classical trick of AWK.

Comment: If you put `FNR==1{next}` as the first line of your awk script then you could just pass in the raw files as awk arguments `awk 'FNR==1{next} {...}' test.csv test.csv` instead of preprocessing them with bash and sed `awk 'FNR==1{next} {...}' <(sed 1d test.csv) <(sed 1d test.csv)`.

Comment: Thanks Pierre for the solution.
I would let you know the outcome. 
Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: Thanks Ed, would consider the comments mentioned by you while checking the solution.
Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: @EdMorton: I also thought about the possibility to put a condition similar to `FNR==1{next}` inside of the AWK script but I was quite sure you would propose it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} 
            NR==1; 
            NR==FNR {if($14=="Credit") b[k] += $15; 
                     else if($14=="Debit") b[k] -= $15; next} 
            b[k]' file{,}

EntryId,datasource,Id,bookID,securId,Type,transfer,event,ActivityType,curr_code,sourceSystemDate,actualDate,accNumber,dr_cr_Type,dr_cr_Amount,remarks,asOfDate,custregion,custName,GLSuffix,product,Code,Domicile,departCode,TXT1,TXT2,TXT3
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,340,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,900,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582327_INR_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Credit,300,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
2582328_USD_20200305_20200305,IND_DATA,2582328,GAS_REGRESSION_CURVE,CL,NYLON Future (O),42267,NA,,INR,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,1941062,Debit,10,Settlement,2020-03-05T00:00:00+05:00,PM Clearing,PM Clearing,Unrealized,GAS,N,Broker_PM Clear_3784,,2020-06-01,2020-05-19,
```

which prints the header as well, if not needed remove `NR==1;`

Comment: Hi, 
would try the solution and let you know. 
Thanks & Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: Thank you all .. Ed, Pierre and Karakfa
All solutions worked fine. except for one hurdle related to floating number.
When the file has millions of rows it has number summation issue; value comes like 1.05389e+06.
Due to this comparison [Dr=Cr] won't match.
In my earlier assignment had used printf "%.2f\n" for the value to have 2 decimals calculation.
Tried the same in the samples, the syntax issue are noted.
Should i be applying printf "%.2f\n" to $15 or the balance [$1 "," $2]?
Please let me know.
Thanks & Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: One more important point noted is the tremendous performance, response is in 1-2 seconds.
Appreciate this.

Comment: Thank you all for solution. All solutions worked ..Regards